# Workflow Foundation suitability

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I need to build a workflow based solution and need some advice.
First of all, there should be a canvas style editor where a user can create workflows. Then, they will be used in a form based workflow process, where the user answers questions and the system will guide them through the steps based on the workflow. There can also be actions, such as sending emails.

The question is: can WF be used for this? I need to use the MS stack.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe the answer is Yes. But am really interested in any war stories from production use: how well does it work in practice?

Comment: As I said in the other comment, I skipped WF for now as I'm building a proof of concept. No war stories here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use workflow to do this.

For the execution part it seems a very good fit.

For the end user designing workflows it depends. The workflow designer used in VS2010 can be rehosted in your own applications without to much work. It is a WPF control though so the client application needs to be able to load and display WPF controls. This rules ASP.NET and Silverlight out but will work fine with WinForms and obviously a WFP app.

Another thing with the designer is that you have to enter VB expressions and in the rehosted designer there is no IntelliSense making this a lot harder. Well there is a [workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/07f89fc0-81ff-4e85-a974-013b15b62f50) for that but it requires VS2010 DLL's. And the expressions can be anything you can do in .NET so that includes potential nasty things like Process.Start().

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had seen the rehosted designer solution, but seems a bit too complex for a business user to mess around with. As this is for a proof of concept app I didn't use WF, I just wrote a quick and dirty engine reading the workflow from xml. Now I'm considering Silverlight for the management canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The rehosted designer is actually very to use, and since all the artifacts for constructing your workflow are provided.